# need help in html::tagFilter

Tags: perl, html-parsing

I wrote a filter like this in perl

```
my $tf = HTML::TagFilter->new(
            allow => {
                img => { src => [] },
                b   => { all => [] },
                i   => { all => [] },
                em  => { all => [] },
                u   => { all => [] },
                s   => { all => [] }
            }
        );

$message_body = $tf->filter($message_body);
```

now what I needed from this filter to do is allowing the given tags, and for img to allow the src attribute. The code gives great results except for tag like this `<img src="cid:img.png" alt="Smiley face">` it just return `<img>` instead of `<img src="sid:imp.png">` which is what I want, does any one here knows why?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set [skip_xss_protection](http://search.cpan.org/~wross/HTML-TagFilter-1.03/TagFilter.pm#skip_xss_protection) to 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TagFilter;

my $tf = HTML::TagFilter->new(
            allow => {
                img => {src => []},
                b   => { all => [] },
                i   => { all => [] },
                em  => { all => [] },
                u   => { all => [] },
                s   => { all => [] }
            },
            skip_xss_protection => 1,
        );

my $html = qq{<img src="cid:img.png" alt="Smiley face">};

$html = $tf->filter($html);
print $html;
```

prints:

```
<img src="cid:img.png">
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your `src` attribute isn't being passed through is because of the module's cross-site scripting protection. The value `cid:img.png` is rejected as an invalid URL, and so the attribute is removed.

The tidiest way to get around this is to extend the list of valid protocols to include `cid`, like this:

```
my @protocols = $tf->xss_permitted_protocols;
push @protocols, 'cid';
$tf->xss_permitted_protocols(@protocols);

$message_body = $tf->filter($message_body);
```

If you set `log_rejects => 1` when you create the `HTML::TagFilter` object then you can examine the values returned by `$tf->report` to see the module's reasons for rejecting each component of the HTML.